bottom sheet modal not working in android
I am using bottom sheet modal for a list of cites for a mobile app using react native my modal is working in ios properly and i can scroll down to the bottom without having an issue but in android the list does not move at all and i try falt list and mapping.
here is my code:
<BottomSheetModal
                    ref={bottomSheetmodalRefCity}
                    index={0}
                    snapPoints={snapPoints}
                    backgroundStyle={{borderRadius:30}}
                    style={{backgroundColor:"white",
                    borderRadius:30,
                      shadowColor: "#000",
                    shadowOffset: {
                      width: 0,
                      height: 12,
                    },
                    shadowOpacity: 0.58,
                    shadowRadius: 8.00,
                    
                    elevation: 6,}}
                  >
 <View className="mt-5 items-end pb-48">
  <Text className="font-[Bold] text-lg mr-6 pt-1">choose a city</Text>
  <ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  
  >
  
  {cityData.map((item) => (
    <View
      key={item.key}
      className="mx-8 my-3 bg-white w-28 h-8 rounded-md items-end justify-center"
      style={{
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 4,
        elevation: 3,
        ...Platform.select({
          ios: {
            shadowOpacity: 0.3,
            shadowRadius: 4,
          },
          android: {
            elevation: 4,
          },
        }),
      }}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          handleItemPress(
            item.value,
            SetSelectedCityR,
            SetSelectedCity,
            bottomSheetmodalRefCity
          )
        }
      >
        <Text className="fons-[Bold] text-lg pr-2">{item.value}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  ))}
  </ScrollView>
</View>


            </BottomSheetModal>

